# Не получается сохранить модель в yii

Tags: sql, mvc, yii, php, mysql

Не получается сохранить модель в yii

```
<?
public function actionTest() {
    $model=User::model()->findByPk(1);
    /* print_r($model); - находит все нормально */
    $model->name = 'новое имя';
    if($model->save()) { /* Условие не выполняется */
        echo 'ура!';
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую писать примерно так

```
$model->name = 'новое имя';
if($model->validate()){
    $result = $model->save();
}
else{
    $result = $model->getErrors();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в модели атрибут name указан как НЕ СТРОКОВЫЙ. Попробуйте $model->save(**false**). False как параметр метода save говорит, чтобы yii не валидировал входящие данные.

Comment: нашел проблему, array('verifyCode','captcha'), Спасибо